# Facebook public feed API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-public-feed-api

i'm working on project which mostly is a data-mining from social networks, so far, i've done twitter and it have really nice API, which allows me to pick an endpoint and recieve alredy filltered twits as streaming data. Now i'm working on a facebook, and there comes the question: with Graph API i would be able to get public feed of some definite page, but what if i would like to recieve posts from as many people as possible? Does Facebook Public Feed API works as Twitter's, and gives me data from as many sources as possible, or i missunderstood something?

Comment: I have same Question but right now getting one Clue that us `public feed API` but how to use i don't know so if you know please comment it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're look for the Facebook Search API. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/

You'll need an app with a token to access these. Some might need higher permissions though, but the generic one will work to search commons actions types (post, places, etc) who're publicly available on the platform.

You won't be able to search for private publications. Unless you search user who gave you direct permissions to read their timeline (one by one).

Comment: But if i need to search specific keyword like "#Odoo" then in search `#` is ignored then what can i do ?

Answer (score 6):

Facebook has restricted public feed api usage and its now available only to handful no of teams: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed

> Access to the Public Feed API is restricted to a limited set of media publishers and usage requires prior approval by Facebook. You cannot apply to use the API at this time.