# Query public posts / feeds from facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-public-feed-api

I am building an app in which user will enter some words.

I need to get data about these words from facebook public feeds / public posts .

After getting data, i will display post / feed permanent_uri in my app.

i have read out following link but i do not know where to start. From whom i need to contact and on which platform.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed/

i also read out link [Facebook public feed API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19298125/facebook-public-feed-api)
In which one person answers that fb restricts this now.

Can i get public posts / feeds from facebook ?

Comment: The document you linked to say: "Access to the Public Feed API is restricted to a limited set of media publishers and usage requires prior approval by Facebook. You cannot apply to use the API at this time."

Comment: so i cannot use facebook to extract public feeds. right ?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: It used to be possible to get public data from any Facebook page. Since the Canbridge Analytica "scandal" they have implemented higher restrictions and now you need to get your app reviewed and approved. Which seems to be a nightmare as they ask you to make a video of how users would use your app. Pretty ridiculous... See this article: https://engt.co/2QVnLJy